Cardinal Exponentiation Inequalities
For the set of functions between $A$ and $B$, $B^A$, what is the relationship between $|B^A|$ and $|B|$ if $|B| > 1$ and $|A| > 1$? To me it's clear that $|B^A| > |A|$ as we have $|B| \ge 2$ so this follows from Cantor's Theorem. It's less clear to me how to relate to this to $B$. I think at least we know $|B^A| \ge |B|$ since we can inject $B$ into $B^A$ via the set of constant functions.
Though this equality need not be strict as in the case of: $|\mathbb{N}_0^2| = |\mathbb{N}_0|$. However, if we do have $|B| \le |A|$ then we do have strict inequality since $|B| \le |A| < |B^A|$. Is there a more general rule?
